# ListPreference that contains images

Tags: android, image, listpreference

Is it possible to make a custom ListPreference that contains only image and no radio button like this?

[image]

I'm not sure if that is ListPreference, so if its not please tell me how to achieve it. Thank you.

Comment: to me, it looks like a GridView

Comment: @Blackbelt you means that is a dialog with GridView?

Comment: yep, a GridView within a Dialog

Comment: if thats the case, how can I use it in the preference xml file?

Answer (score 0):

try use [this library](https://github.com/xdtianyu/ColorPicker)
it gives you

[image]

and on click

[image]

and it update the summary without single line of code

[image]